# ToText in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

Function `ToText` is pretty straightfoward yet it doesn't seem to work.

I've used ibm documentation
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic629.html

No matter what I use, I get

> Boolean value expected

Is there a way for Crystal Report to 'get' that I'm passing a number in my `ToText`?

```
ToText({numbertoexport},2,"",",")
```

Comment: What is your full formula and where are you writing this formula?

Comment: the formula is below.   that answered my question.  I was writing my formula in 'Selections'....lol.   sorry i am very new to C-Report.  The 'where' tipped me.    thank you.

Comment: NP... Different windows will retrun different datatypes, we need to just understand the logic.. thats all